# How do I show a collection field (with handlebars) on a routed page?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a main rooms page that routes into a child roomPage, with url as `rooms/:_id`.

So I have a collection helper that aims to find a user within a specific room.

```
Rooms.helpers({
    endUser: function() {  
       return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.receiver }).username; 
    }
});
```

Each room structure is:

```
_id: YY, //the roomId
receiver:  XX,
people: [receiver, Meteor.userId()]
```

So how do I make `{{endUser}}` appear in the routed roomPage? It appears in the main page `rooms` but not in `rooms/:id`. console.log shows all users correctly and all receivers in those rooms where the rooms are wrapped within `{{# each rooms}}`. I also subscribed to the `user` publish but its no difference.

Where its working in main page.

```
{{#each rooms}}
     {{ endUser }}
{{/each}}
```

This is how im making the helper.

```
Template.roomPage.helpers({   
   roomPage: function () {
      return Rooms.find({ roomId : Router.current().params._id });
   }
});
```

Somehow this.receiver shows undefined in console.log within the route roomPage.

Comment: would you please edit the post and show us some blaze code where it's working

Comment: Done. It's basically a loop through all rooms with each function. Somehow this works in rooms but not in rooms/:_id. I suspect it's bcos of the route into rooms/:_id and I need to either tweak the helper or the blaze HTML format. Like maybe '{{room.endUser }}'. Or with _Id =roomId etc. Both not working by the way. I tried.

Comment: @Thinkerer Do you use Iron Router?

Comment: Yes I use iron router but im trying to move to flow router ...hence moving data context and subscription to template level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have access in the `room` Object first. I assume your route has subscription to only one `room`. what you can do for this is similar to this

```
Template.xxx.helpers({
    singleRoom: function(){
        return Rooms.find({ _id: Router.current().params._id });
    }
});
```

in Blaze ,

```
{{#with singleRoom}}
    {{endUser}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: it's dependent on how you made the subscription. the most common use case would be passing room object id as a params via node and subscribe accordingly.

Comment: Hi Faysal, I did as you mentioned. (Also attached code above). Somehow when i put in the `{{#with roomPage}}` even the `|` or static content within the html dissapears.

Comment: don't make your template name and helper name same. try with different helper name.

Comment: Ah ok finally it works! 
The problem is with the helper. It should be `_id` rather than `roomId`. Also I need to subscribe to the main collection `rooms` as well. Thanks for the great help Faysal!!!